# How do I export a single private key from the command line in OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line, keychain, private-key

I need to export one private key (identity) from my OSX Keychain from the command line. Using `security`, I can only figure out how to export all private keys (identities) as a single pkcs12 (p12) file. How do I export a specific one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/torsten/keychain_access works, but it doesn't support filtering by type. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/torsten/keychain_access/pull/1) for this functionality. Until it is accepted, you can try [my fork](https://github.com/hborders/keychain_access/tree/added_type_parameter).

```
./keychain_access -p password_for_exported_private_key "Name of private key"
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that if you're trying to export "Apple Push Services: some.id" push certificate p12 it will just throw an error.